# Getting Problem in apache server while deploying spring boot application on tomcat 9: Status 404 - Not Found

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g5j2.jpg)I have developed application that is build in spring boot which is working fine in my local but while deploying on production i'm getting error.

HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: Could you share your error log?

Comment: Not geeting anything in my error log and i have attached my tomcat image

Comment: @SatyajitBiswal no, you have not attached an image. Sorry.

Comment: @Taschi Sorry i have attached now you can check.

Comment: did you check if it's something related to the fact that if tomcat has it's automatic deployment feature enabled will set the context name of your application to the same name as the war file? so if you test locally as localhost:8080/ , after you deploy to tomcat it will be serveraddress/<name of war file> ?

Comment: is a web or api? what is the endpoint which works in local ? and what is the endpoint which throws the 404 error? Is a common error on my team!

Comment: @JRichardsz it is web , on local I have give default / mapping to home page but it's starting on deployment server

Comment: @Henrique Forlani  I have done configuration localhost/ on server configuration file , my war file is with name ROOT.war . So are you saying I should give my context path as war name and also in my configuration file I should give serveraddress/contextpath

Comment: @SatyajitBiswal you should just check if accessing via serveraddress/ROOT works

Answer (score 1):

## Check your tomcat health

- Remove your war and start it
- Go to localhost:port and a tomcat home page must be renderized:

[image: tomcat]

If your tomcat does not show the expected home page, try to fix it before to deploy your app.

## Possible cause

According to your comments, you issue could be this:

You java web app shows the home page in your localhost (eclipse) at:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

But when you deploy in a tomcat, you are using a war file which is deployed in webapps folder. For example:

```
acme-web.war
```

So if you deploy this war in your tomcat hosted in

```
http://localhost:1234 (which must render the tomcat home page)
```

Your app will be available at:

```
http://localhost:1234/acme-web
```

There is a technique to show your web instead the tomcat home page. Just ask me!

I hope this helps you.